# Maximal Thurston--Bennequin number of boundary knot classes in contact handlebodies

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, contact-geometry, legendrian-submanifolds

Let $H$ be a **contact handlebody**.  In other words, $H$ is a small regular neighborhood of a Legendrian graph in a contact $3$-manifold (wlog $\mathbb R^3$).  Equivalently, $H=(\Sigma\times[0,1],dt+\lambda)$ where $\Sigma$ is a compact bordered Riemann surface equipped with a Liouville form $\lambda$.  The boundary $\partial H$ is a convex hypersurface with 'dividing set' given by $\partial\Sigma\times\{\frac 12\}=:D$.

Given a(n isotopy class of) simple closed curve $\alpha$ on $\partial H$, pushing it inwards defines a smooth knot $K_\alpha$ in $H$.

> What is known about $tb_\max(K_\alpha)$ the maximal Thurston–Bennequin number of a Legendrian representative of $K_\alpha$?

If I recall correctly, a standard construction gives a Legendrian representative of $K_\alpha$ with $tb$ given by the minimal geometric intersection number between $\alpha$ and the dividing set $D$.  This is not sharp in general, for the following reason.  For any simple closed curve $\beta\subseteq\partial H$ bounding a disk in $H$ and intersecting $\alpha$ exactly once, we have $K_\alpha=K_{\tau_\beta\alpha}$, but $\alpha$ and $\tau_\beta\alpha$ need not have the same minimal geometric intersection number with $D$.

**Addendum** As Marc Kegel notes in a comment, $K_\alpha$ need not be null-homologous, in which case $tb_\max(K_\alpha)$ is not an integer, but rather a *framing* of $K_\alpha$.  The assertion from the previous paragraph that $tb_\max(K_\alpha)\leq i(\alpha,D)$ is meant relative the framing of $\alpha$ induced by the boundary $\partial H$.

Comment: I am sure you know this, but let me mention it for the record: $K_\alpha$ might not be nullhomologous in $H$. In that case, $tb$ would not be defined. If $K_\alpha$ is nullhomologous in $H$ it bounds a Seifert surface in $H$ and thus $tb$ and the Seifert genus g are defined. Then a contact handlebody is tight and the Bennequin bound $tb\leq 2g -1$ holds (which will in general not be sharp).

Comment: John Pardon, I see that you have created ([tag:legendrian-submanifolds]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://mathoverflow.net/tags/legendrian-submanifolds/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after six months [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).